# How can I deserialize Xml list using Restsharp?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <xml> 
            <item> 
                    <accountid>1</accountid> 
                    <accounttypeid>1</accounttypeid> 
                    <accounttypename/> 
                    <accountbankid>1</accountbankid> 
                    <accountbankname/> 
                    <accountsaldo>0</accountsaldo> 
            </item> 
            <item> 
                    <accountid>2</accountid> 
                    <accounttypeid>1</accounttypeid> 
                    <accounttypename/> 
                    <accountbankid>2</accountbankid> 
                    <accountbankname/> 
                    <accountsaldo>0</accountsaldo> 
            </item> 
            ... 
    </xml>
```

I want to deserialize this xml list to POCO object which is

```
public class Account 
{ 
        public string AccountId { get; set; } 
        public string AccountTypeId { get; set; } 
        public string AccountTypeName { get; set; } 
        public string AccountBankId { get; set; } 
        public string AccountBankName { get; set; } 
        public string AccountSaldo { get; set; } 
}
```

I found great product [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for working with rest client. I want to use its deserializer and I tried 2 approaches.

1) I tried

`request.RootElement = "item";`

`var response = Execute<Account>(request);`

and I only got first Item element which is logical.

2) When I try something like

`request.RootElement = "xml";`

`var response = Execute<List<Account>>(request);`

I got null.

Where am I wrong with this?

**UPDATE**: The solution is in accepted answer comments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work if you rename the `Account` class to `Item` and use `Execute<List<Item>>(request)`. You don't need to specify a RootElement value.

Comment: Hmm, I got ErrorMessage = "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Does it work if you set `RootElement = "xml";`? I thought it worked without that, but maybe I'm remembering incorrectly.

Comment: and if that doesn't work, try setting RootElement and naming the class `item`

Comment: Nope, it won't work. I tried both of the cases. Maybe I should pull from the github and create test for this case (adding the sample xml)

Comment: I'll try it out tonight and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ok, this is how I did it, couldn't go to sleep :)  I created `public class XmlItems : List<item>
        {
        } and then Execute<XmlItems>(request)

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion :) I thought RootElement + `List<T>` would work. It probably should. If you submit a test, I will be motivated to add it.

Comment: Why is it necessary to derive from List<T> into a concrete class? Is there a way to get this done while still using a generic list?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what's wrong, but I'm sure John will be by soon to let you know :-)   In the meanwhile, why not just do it the manual way:

```
    var root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
    var accounts = from it in root.Element("xml").Elements("item")
                   select new Account() {
                                            AccountId = it.Element("accountid").Value,
                                            AccountTypeId = it.Element("accounttypeid").Value,
                                            AccountTypeName = it.Element("accounttypename").Value,
                                            AccountBankId = it.Element("banktypeid").Value,
                                            AccountBankName = it.Element("banktypename").Value,
                                            AccountSaldo = it.Element("accountsaldo").Value
                                        };
```

It's so clean and easy with XLinq.  By adding a few extension methods to XElement you can make it even cleaner and resilient to missing elements/attributes.

Comment: Yes, I'm fine with linq2xml but I wanted to create client api for fast development, without the need for manual coding. I need a working vertical to show to my colleagues. 10x for the answer anyway!